# How to Get Photos Info From photo library iphone?

Tags: iphone, photo

Is it possible to get the complete photo info in photo library like the date and time  photo is saved .I found that we can get all photos from photo library using asserts library is there any class that get photo complete info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Assets` library and [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html). I'll put some code as sampler.

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = nil;
NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:assetURL
    resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
        NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
        imageMetadata          = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
        [self addEntriesFromDictionary:metadata];
    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
[library autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Srikar I could ge† the info about the photo but There is no time information in metadata.It is not showing any time info like at what time it is saved.